# "uninitialized constant ActionView::CompiledTemplates::GMap" error when using ym4r_gm plugin

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, google-maps, ruby-on-rails-plugins

So I am somewhat new to Rails 3, and I am trying to integrate Google Maps with my Rails application.

I installed ym4r_gm from git://github.com/rorcraft.ym4r_gm.git, and I followed the tutorial on http://blog.brijeshshah.com/google-maps-in-ruby-on-rails/, and http://blog.brijeshshah.com/google-maps-in-rails-3/ .

After following the tutorial, I tried to run my application but I get an error that says "uninitialized constant ActionView::CompiledTemplates::GMap" regarding the "<%= raw Gmap.header %>" line. I have already installed the ym4r_gm-0.2.0 gem, and the ym4r-0.6.1 gem. Any suggestions on how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that the gems you're trying to use in your Rails app are actually included in your Gemfile as well as being installed on your local machine.

Check out [Ruby Gems](https://rubygems.org/) for the exact line to include in your Gemfile. In this case, it's:

```
gem "ym4r_gm", "~> 0.2.0"
```

When you push your code to a production server like Heroku, the Gemfile tells Heroku which gems to pull down and install on the server. Also run this command when you're done.

```
bundle install
```